# Using a loop to insert all entries in a List into an SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite, loops

I've written a script in Python which pulls some links from a given website, and stores the URLs in a list.

I want to enter these URLs into an SQLite database, where each item in the list is stored in a new row.

I have the length of the list, but I can't figure out what the loop function would be to pull the relevant item from the list, and then move on to the next one.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a total moron - this was very, very simple. This works.

```
 for x in range(0, ext_len):
     cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO sources_log(timestamp, web, sources) VALUES(?,?,?)''', (datetime.now(), site, ext[x]))    
     db.commit()
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to iterate through each row to do this.

Usually you do something like this:

```
# Create your database
db = sqlite3.connect('data/mydb')
# Create a cursor to execute your request
cursor = db.cursor()
# Create your table
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE links (url VARCHAR(100))''')
# Insert your list into the table
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO links(url) VALUES(?)''', yourList)
# Commit and close
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid. The following error occurs: 

InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: Sorry, my example wasn't very clear. Are you using a database already created ? Otherwise you should create a table before the INSERT statement.

Comment: No, I had that covered, I used a CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS command before the INSERT command. 

The issue is, I think, you can't put a list directly into a column row. I was able to iterate through the list using the loop below.

Comment: Well I'm glad you worked it out, my answer was just wrong. I need to go back to my sql lessons.